# Make div in div in div scrollable with overflow

Tags: html, css

I have an React application and having a slightly bigger problem with some CSS stuff.

I have an view which is divided in 2 parts. But those two parts are lying in one bigger component. The left part is displaying some contacts and on the right I want to display details of those contacts. Now I want to make the left part scrollable like a list, but the right part just stay fixed on its position. Also the height of the left part should always stay as high as the current screen size. I am using [Bulma CSS](http://bulma.io) as my base CSS framework.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="pane main-content" id="mainPane">
    <div class="contacts-view">
        <h1 class="title">My Title</h1>
        <div class="">Other Stuff</div>
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column is-3">
               <div class="columns is-multiline">
                   <div class="column"></div>
                   <div class="column"></div>
                   <div class="column"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-9"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a quick sketch of how it looks:

[image]

Current relevant CSS:

```
.main-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
}
.pane {
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
    flex: 1;
}

.columns {
    margin-left: -0.75rem;
    margin-right: -0.75rem;
    margin-top: -0.75rem;
}

.column {
    display: block;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-negative: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    padding: 0.75rem;
}
```

For better explanation. The component with class **column is-3** should be scrollable but all other parts should stay fixed with no scroll. 
I tried:

```
.is-3
    overflow:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
```

But I found out that I have to set the height of **is-3** because otherwise my screen is just expanded to the bottom. But I can not set a fixed height to it, because my screen size is dynamic and depended on the size of **#mainPane**. But I can also not set it to 100% because then the screen is also expanded at the bottom. Do you have any suggestions how I can solve this with CSS ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flexbox layout.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1uqyap7m/)**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
  background: lightblue;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 0; /*ADDED 2021*/
}
.sidebar {
  background: lightgreen;
  overflow: auto;
}
.main {
  flex: 1;
  background: pink;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div style="height:200vh;">sidebar</div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div style="height:200vh;">main</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```